# Creating a temporary file with .pdf extension php tempnam

Tags: php

Is it possible to create a .pdf file extension when using tempname? I need to send an e-mail with a file created using tempname. (I can send the file, but I need the .pdf extension)

Comment: Does this really make sense? If the E-Mail doesn't contain any other attachments, why not name it `attachment.pdf` or something meaningful related to the E-Mails content?

Comment: I want to use a temporary location to store the file (not in my application directory). If you can think of another way let me know.

Comment: @Chris but why does the temporary file need to have a .PDF extension?

Comment: @Pekka  It is going to be attached to an e-mail

Comment: @Chris but when you attach it to your E-Mail, you can fetch the data from the temporary file, but name the attachment anything you want. No need to give that the `tempnam()` name

Comment: @Pekka Unfortunately I am using CodIgniter and they don't have an API to name the attachment something different

Comment: @Chris then how about creating a temporary directory, storing the PDF file with a proper name in there, and using that?

Comment: @Pekka I guess I can do that, but I was trying to avoid creating a writable application directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the filename any name you like in the MIME header within the multipart message.

Comment: Could you add an sample of the Mime header for the readers that aren't used to it, don't need to google about it too.

Answer (score 5):

```
$tempname = tempnam('', 'report_');
rename($tempname, $tempname .= '.pdf');

// now use the new filename as you wish
var_dump($tempname, is_file($tempname));
```

By default such files are created with the strictest level of privileges possible. Typically they're only readable by the current user.  It may be necessary to make these files group-readable:

```
chmod($original, 0640);
```

Or even world-readable, although this is inadvisable:

```
chmod($original, 0644);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible with tempnam. You'll have to write your own function for that, for example using the current time. The problem here is to avoid race conditions, but that can possibly be solved by including the PID in the filename, like this:

```
do {
  $filename = rand();
  $filename .= '.'. str_replace(' ', '.', microtime());
  $filename .= '.'. getmypid();
  $filename .= '.pdf';
} while(file_exists($filename));
```

If the directory is shared between different machines the PID is not guaranteed to be unique. In that case, also include the hostname of the current machine (as returned by gethostname).

Answer (score 0):

I use a function like this for temporary unique names:

```
function tempnam_sfx ($path, $suffix) {
if(!is_dir($path)){
    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}    

do {
    $file = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . mt_rand () . $suffix;
} while (file_exists($file));            

return $file;
}
```